# Multi-dimensional ndarray set operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, pandas

I have the need to run the set difference of two potentially large multidimensional `numpy.ndarrays`.
My tests have proven unsuccessful trying to extend the `numpy.setdiff1d` to work for multidimensional arrays without throwing the following `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: Cannot change data-type for object array.
```

The data in these arrays is a long and a string.

I have the two following arrays:

```
A = [[0L 'a']
     [2L 'c']
     [1L 'b']
     [3L 'b']
     [0L 'd']]

B = [[1L 'b']
     [0L 'a']
     [4L 'b']]
```

The expected result is the set difference `S = A - B` which are the pairs `((0,d), (2,c), (3,b))`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a structured array as long as the shape along which you're doing set comparisons is 1d (here it is, since you have an effective 1d array of pairs):

```
A = np.array([(0L, 'a'),
              (2L, 'c'),
              (1L, 'b'),
              (3L, 'b'),
              (0L, 'd')], dtype=[('n', long), ('l', 'S1')])

B = np.array([(1L, 'b'),
              (0L, 'a'),
              (4L, 'b')], dtype=[('n', long), ('l', 'S1')])

S = np.setdiff1d(A, B)

>>> S
array([(2L, 'c'), (3L, 'b'), (0L, 'd')], 
      dtype=[('n', '<i8'), ('l', 'S1')])
```

Comment: This looks like the correct way to do so, but I cannot change the array dtype like you mentioned. My np.arrays are returned from the Pandas .values() method. The dtype of those are object. I am trying to convert them to your suggested dtype using .astype but i am getting the following type error: expected a readable buffer object. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, yes sometimes converting certain arrays into structured arrays can be tricky.  Take a look at `np.core.rec.fromarrays`.  Also, there may be a pandas solution so you don't have to conver to numpy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's set operations here:

```
In [66]: s = set(tuple(x) for x in A).difference(tuple(x) for x in B)

In [67]: np.array(list(s))
Out[67]: 
array([['0', 'd'],
       ['2', 'c'],
       ['3', 'b']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```